# Connect Nginx and Django containers [host not found in upstream]

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've created 2 containers for both, Django and Nginx. It's working perfectly on my desktop, but when I pull my images from Docker Hub in an AWS EC2 instence and run, I got this error:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2021/08/24 15:09:39 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "my_server:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "my_server:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
```

Here is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  my_server:
    image: user/image-app
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: user/image-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - my_server

volumes:
  static:
```

My *default.conf* file

```
upstream django {
    server my_server:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
}
```

Even after I try to add a network and change to "8000:80" the Django ports like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  scrimmage:
    image: user/image-app
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    networks:
      - django_network

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: user/image-nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - scrimmage
    networks:
      - django_network

volumes:
  static:

networks:
  django_network:
    driver: bridge
```

And change the the *default.conf* to this:

```
upstream django {
    server my_server;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }
}
```

Still not working. Also this changes don't work at my local machine.
The first configuration works fine locally, like I said before.

Comment: Totally out of the blue, but did you sign into docker hub? It seems to me that you're trying to pull a private image.

Comment: I did, I just omitted my real username/image-name. The problem is when I run, not when pulling the image.

Comment: What version of docker do you running have on the ec2 instance? Please look at the compatibility matrix for docker compose and docker versions https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: 20.10.4 on the EC2, 20.10.7 on my Desktop.

Comment: Already changed to the same 20.10.7 on EC2 with Ubuntu. Same problem.